# Ruby on Rails mysql2 connection last_id always returns 0

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5, mysql 5.7 and I need to get the last id of the previous insert statement(which inserts multiple records using load data infile command), and I don't want to just use `Model.last.id` as it may happen that another process has inserted new records just before the first process asks for the last_id, so I tried using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.last_id`, as uses a mysql call that works per connection, however this method always returns 0, although new records are inserted and the primary key is auto incremented. So any clue ?

Comment: You can try `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")`

Comment: indeed this returns the correct value, however I don't want to depend on this as this command may change with newer version of mysql, so it's better to use the gem instead which will handle versions changes.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this recently. The reason it was returning 0 for me was because I was outside of a transaction. Once I did it in a transaction it worked fine.